# Load jQuery plugin on specific pages in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Got myself into a pickle with Angular JS. While I somewhat love it, I don't understand it enough to make full use of it yet. I would appreciate some help. 
The goal:
Load jQuery Plugin [Liquid Slider](http://liquidslider.com/) only on the home page.

What's being used on index.html page (snippet):

```
<head>
 <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app-dev.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- For Liquid Slider -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/liquid-slider/js/jquery.liquid-slider.min.js"></script>
<script>
  //Bit of a no no from what i've read
  setTimeout(function(){
  $('#slider-1').liquidSlider({
        autoSlide: true,
        autoSlideInterval: 1500,
        dynamicArrows: true
    });
    console.log('success!');
    }, 500);
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
//stuff
<ng-view autoscroll="true" class="main-show"></ng-view>
</body>
```

js/app-dev.js shows:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl : 'views/home-dev.html',                
    })
    .otherwise('/home');
});
```

Currently liquid slider is being called on every page. Looking at the jquery code, it looks like it's running, but no sliding action is happening, I have isolated this by running the liquid slider on its on page with no Angular and it works fine. I am lead to believe I have implemented something incorrectly. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

-- update --
I've been looking into directives and got something working

```
app.directive('mySlider', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element){
                 $('#slider-1').liquidSlider({
                    autoSlide: true,
                    autoSlideInterval: 1500,
                    forceAutoSlide:true,
                    dynamicArrows: true,
                    minHeight: 10,
                });

      }
  };
});
```

although that work, I don't think it's the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a directive is a great way to go because you can attach the slider to any specific element you want.  However, your directive has the "slider-1" ID hard-coded.  You want that to be dynamic so you can attach it to any element:

```
app.directive('mySlider', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element){
                 $(element).liquidSlider({
                    autoSlide: true,
                    autoSlideInterval: 1500,
                    forceAutoSlide:true,
                    dynamicArrows: true,
                    minHeight: 10,
                });
      }
  };
});
```

This will initiate the liquid slider on the HTML element that has a `my-slider` attribute, like this:

```
<div my-slider>Test contents</div>
```

You can even go further and make the other liquid slider attributes dynamic like this:

```
app.directive('mySlider', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                 $(element).liquidSlider({
                    autoSlide: attrs.autoSlide==="true",
                    autoSlideInterval: autoSlideInterval,
                    forceAutoSlide: attrs.forceAutoSlide==="true",
                    dynamicArrows: attrs.dynamicArrows==="true",
                    minHeight: attrs.minHeight,
                });
      }
  };
});
```

And set these dynamic options like this in your HTML:

```
<div my-slider auto-slide="true" auto-slide-interval="1500" 
    force-auto-slide="true" dynamic-arrows="true" min-height="10">Test contents</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a helpful answer and going above and beyond. I knew having slider-1 ID hardcoded put me at a disadvantage. But the technique you provided will really help me to make the website more dynamic. I appreciate you taking the time to answer the question for me